# findById causes StackOverflowError but findAll workds fine

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a strange problem with a spring boot endpoint that calls JpaRepository findById(). When ever I send a GET request to the endpoint /v1/goals/{id} a stack overflow error occurs, while GET requests to /v1/goals work fine.

Edit: added the error message to the bottom

Simplified Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class GoalController {

    private final GoalServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    GoalController(GoalServiceImpl service) { this.service = service; }

    @GetMapping("/v1/goals")
    ResponseEntity<List<Goal>> allGoals() { return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getGoals(), HttpStatus.OK); }

    @GetMapping("/v1/goals/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<String> singleGoal(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getGoalById(id).toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Simplified Service class:

```
@Service
public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService {

    private final GoalRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public GoalServiceImpl(GoalRepository repository) { this.repository = repository; }

    public Goal getGoalById(Long id) {
        return repository
                .findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new GoalNotFoundException(id));
    }

    public List<Goal> getGoals() { return repository.findAll(); }

}
```

Simplified Entity class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Goal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long goalId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "goal")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "goal")
    private List<Milestone> milestones;

}
```

Simplified Milestone Entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Milestone {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long milestone_id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "goal_id")
    private Goal goal;
```

Simplified User Entity:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "user")
    private List<Goal> goals;

}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.motivate.api.user.User$HibernateProxy$KaIclPZ9.toString(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at com.motivate.api.goal.Goal.toString(Goal.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
    at com.motivate.api.user.User.toString(User.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at com.motivate.api.user.User$HibernateProxy$KaIclPZ9.toString(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: One endpoint is using the objects and serializing the full list of objects, while in the one that fails, you use toString on the instance. Check the error and what is triggering the stack, but a guess is that the problem is in your toString implementation. It isn't a JSON serialization method and is probably going through the full object recursively.

Comment: Thanks @Chris - I've added the error to the question. I'm not explicitly implementing toString, it's being handled by lombok, and I'm using JsonIgnore and JsonIgnoreProperties to try and limit potential recursion. Could the toString still be the problem?

Comment: Lombok doesn't use JSON (Jackson?) annotations, so yes, it is its implementation of the toString method causing your issue. Chances are good it calls toString on all your properties, calling recursion on the user-goal relationship. Lombok is great, but only if you know how it implements things. Simple solution - don't call toString to return a string and instead pass the goal instance to the ResponseEntity constructor for serialization.

Comment: I agree with Chris on this, I'm unsure why you even call toString as I can't see how that would be useful, but if you really need a String representation of your entity you can always just write your own method to convert it to a string, you just have to maintain it when changing stuff in your entity

Comment: Thank you both, you're right. Changing the type of ResponseEntity and removing toString() solved the issue. I didn't understand how the serialisation worked. @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

provided by Chris and PaulD in the comments:

```
@GetMapping("/v1/goals/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<Goal> singleGoal(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getGoalById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Remove the toString() as that causes the whole object to be serialised by lombok which doesn't take into account the jackson annotations. Change ResponseEntity to be of type Goal and pass in the whole entity.